# TouchableOpacity onLongPress intercepts FlatList scrolling

Tags: android, react-native, onscroll, touchableopacity

I have an issue with using onLongPress on a TouchableOpacity component within a FlatList row. Any time you go to scroll the FlatList, the onLongPress method fires. The onPress method does not have this problem and I *could* use this instead, but it wouldn't be ideal.

I have tried messing with the delayPressIn value for the TouchableOpacity, but nothing I've tried helps.

I've also thought about setting a flag when scrolling starts that I could check in the onLongPress method, but none of the onScroll, onScrollEndDrag, or onScrollBeginDrag methods on FlatList are working.

Does anyone have an idea on fixing the scrolling issue or the onScroll events? If this is a bug, I can just use the onPress event if I have to.

Versions: React 0.55.4, NativeBase: 2.8.1

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, View, Text} from 'native-base';
import MainHeader from '../MainHeader';

export default class PageVehicleList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: 'Vehicle List',
            dataSource: [],
            isRefreshing: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._listenForItems();
    }

    _listenForItems() {
        console.log('_listenForItems');
        new ServerRequest(
            'get_vehicles.php',
            null,
            (data) => {this._getData(data)},
            (error) => {this._errorGettingData(error)}
        );
    }

    _getData(data) {
        console.log('_getData: ', data);
        this.setState({
            dataSource: data,
            isRefreshing: false
        });
    }

    _errorGettingData(error) {
        console.log('_errorGettingData: ' + error);
        this.setState({isRefreshing: false});
    }

    _onClick_add = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PAGE_VEHICLE_ADD');
    }

    _onLongClick_vehicle = (data) => {
        console.log('_onLongClick_vehicle - data: ', data);
        console.log('this.state.isRefreshing: ', this.state.isRefreshing);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PAGE_VEHICLE_ADD', {serial: data});
    }

    _onRefresh() {
        console.log('_onRefresh');
        this.setState({
            isRefreshing: true
        });
        this._listenForItems();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <MainHeader title={this.state.title} func_add={this._onClick_add}/>
                <Content>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dataSource}
                        style={styles.listview}
                        renderItem={(data) => this._renderRow(data)}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.serial.toString()}
                        onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
                        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                        onScroll={() => {console.log('onScroll');}}
                        onScrollEndDrag={() => {console.log('onScrollEndDrag');}}
                        onScrollBeginDrag={() => {console.log('onScrollBeginDrag');}}
                        />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }

    _renderRow(data) {
        console.log('_renderRow - data: ', data);
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onLongPress={() => {this._onLongClick_vehicle(data.item.serial)}}
                >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.col1}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Name:</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.value} numberOfLines={1}>{data.item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Year:</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.value} numberOfLines={1}>{data.item.model_year}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Miles:</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.value} numberOfLines={1}>{data.item.miles}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Make:</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.value} numberOfLines={1}>{data.item.make_model}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#656565'
    },
    listview: {

    },
    separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
    },
    col1: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    col2: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    row: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: 'blue',
        marginRight: 10,
    },
    value: {
        fontSize: 10,
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Trent, have you fixed it, if so could you please share the solution here.
I have flatlist and that cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for any future readers.

While investigating another issue with refresh on pulldown for the FlatList, I stumbled upon a post stating the Content component from NativeBase was just a wrapped ScrollView. I remembered reading something somewhere else about issues with nested ScrollViews. I changed my Content component to just a plain view (NativeBase view) and this solved both issues. My refresh on pulldown started working as well as the onLongPress/scroll issues.